# C, Getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a file called islands.txt with the contents:

```
islandone
islandtwo
islandthree
```

And this my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct island{
    char *name;
    struct island *previous;
} island;

void printIsland(island is){
    printf("%s", is.name);
    if(is.previous && is.previous->name[0] != '\0'){
        printf("%s", is.previous->name);
    }
}

int main(){

    // the file to be read.
    FILE *islandsFile = fopen("islands.txt","r");

    // temporary location to store the name read from the file.
    char name[40];

    // temporary pointer to an island which has been already read for linking.
    island *previousIsland;

    while(fscanf(islandsFile,"%s",name) != EOF){
        // allocate space for a new island and point to it with (*newIsland) pointer
        island *newIsland =malloc(sizeof(island));

        // assign name
        newIsland->name = name;

        // if previousIsland pointer is not null
        // it means there is an island that was read before newIsland in the file

        if(previousIsland){
            // newIsland.previous should hold the address of this previously read island..
            newIsland->previous = previousIsland;
        }
        // now previousIsland is the newIsland..
        previousIsland = newIsland;
        printIsland(*newIsland);
        puts("");
    }

    fclose(islandsFile);
}
```

My expectation of output is:

```
islandone
islandtwoislandone
islandthreeislandtwo
```

Instead all I am getting is segmentation fault. I have tried everything but I am stuck. Where am I getting the segmentation fault here? I am pretty new to C and I have no idea how to debug.

Comment: You could simply debug by adding statements like `printf("executing line %d\n", __LINE__);` everywhere to see what gets executed and what not. But it is better to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Use a debugger, step until you get a segfault, inspect variables - it should give you a clue

Comment: `island *previousIsland;` --> `island *previousIsland=NULL;` and `if(previousIsland){ ... }` --> `newIsland->previous = previousIsland;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, that as well.. But if I do not set it to null, what is it set to?

Comment: @KorayTugay it's not set; Using uninitialized variables causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KorayTugay Cause a segment fault because not explicitly initialized to NULL.

Comment: `malloc` does not returned zero'd data, so an additional error is that `->previous` is uninitialized for the first island allocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need to allocate memory for the name as well. You only allocate for the structure

```
typedef struct island{
    char *name;
    struct island *previous;
} island;
```

so this

```
// assign name
newIsland->name = name;
```

will set the pointer to your array which you have on the stack, but by every loop iteration it will be the same address.

instead do something like

```
newIsland->name = strdup(name);
```

or if you prefer

```
newIsland->name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
strcpy( newIsland->name, name );
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here. In addition to those mentioned by CyberSpock, you have the following code:

```
island *previousIsland; 

while(fscanf(islandsFile,"%s",name) != EOF){
   /* some code omitted */

   if(previousIsland){
        newIsland->previous = previousIsland;
   }
```

The previousIsland variable is uninitialized, and the if may be true the first time, so that the previous pointer points to invalid memory. Then when you get to the end in printIsland, it will continue following the uninitialized pointer, getting to invalid memory. I also see that you don't free() any memory, but that may be becuase you don't care for such a small example.

To debug C programs, a debugger is you friend. Now you don't tell which OS and compiler you use, but if you use gcc, gdb is the matching debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I use OSX and eclipse, but only for input, I compile from terminal with gcc hello.c and just print by ./a.out I will look into debuging as well.